# How to Translate Whole Oracle Apex Application from one language to another

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I want to translate whole apex applicatoin from English to French. 
but there is nothing more than translate messages.

I tried

https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r50/Globalization%20and%20Translation/translating_an_application.html

is there any way to translate whole application from one language to another?

Answer (score 1):

this is the only way to translate an application or alternative you can translate your labels and placeholders etc. in your database and query them into page items after authentication using application process based on the your users languages